# Remove and Add margin-top, Remove and Add background-image to header -on scrolling-

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to add a background image to header when I scroll down and to delete the margin-top too. I would like to add some animation, but it doesn't work out as I planned.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 450) {
        //$(".header").css("margin-top", "0"); <- This works perfectly but its not animated
        $(".header").css("background-image", "url('/images/header.jpg')");
        $(".header").animate({'margin-top': 0}, "slow");
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 450) {
        // $(".header").css("margin-top", "40");<- This works perfectly but its not animated
        $(".header").animate({'margin-top': 40}, "slow");
        $(".header").css("background-image", "none");
    }
});
```

Comment: You could add css to the header that makes every change transition. In your css file add `.header{ transition: 1s ease; margin-top: 0; }` this will make it look animated